# Interpret string as code in parameters

Tags: python, dynamic, parameters

Aloha, i've the following class:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ''' set variable attributes to self '''

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Now i have this String:

```
x = 'a=100, b=200, c=300'
```

I've tried something like this:

```
y = Foo(exec(x))
# or
y = Foo(eval(x))

# should work like this

y = Foo(a=100, b=200, c=300)
```

But this doesn't work. How is it possible to interpret such a string as a parameter handover?

---

## Solution:

Guided from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, arg_str):
        arg_dict = eval('dict({})'.format(arg_str.replace(' ', ',')))
        new_cls = cls()
        for key, value in arg_dict.items():
            setattr(new_cls, key, value)
        return new_cls

x = 'a=100 b=200 c=300'

foo = Foo.from_string(x)
```

Comment: Note that the line `a=100, b=200, c=300` is not, on its own, valid Python code, so you can't `exec`/`eval` it. I would suggest a class method `Foo.from_string` if you have to handle these regularly.

Comment: `y = Foo(eval('x'))` try this as `eval` takes string, while `exec` python code  and object should be `code object` or `string`, so `y = Foo(exec(x))` is an invalid statement.